# Adding 64 bit support to existing 32 bit code, is it difficult?

Tags: c, embedded, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

There is a library which I build against different 32-bit platforms. Now, 64-bit architectures must be supported. What are the most general strategies to extend existing 32-bit code to support 64-bit architectures? Should I use #ifdef's or anything else?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The amount of effort involved will depend entirely on how well written the original code is. In the best possible case there will be no effort involved other than re-compiling. In the worst case you will have to spend a lot of time making your code "64 bit clean".

Typical problems are:

- assumptions about sizes of int/long/pointer/etc
- assigning pointers <=> ints
- relying on default argument or function result conversions (i.e. no function prototypes)
- inappropriate printf/scanf format specifiers
- assumptions about size/alignment/padding of structs (particularly in regard to file or network I/O, or interfacing with other APIs, etc)
- inappropriate casts when doing pointer arithmetic with byte offsets

Comment: +1 Just some additions: A nasty case for integer arguments are va_arg functions: all narrow integer types that correspond to the `...` will be promoted to `int`. Then, code that uses the integer `typeof`s with the correct semantics such as `size_t`, `uintptr_t`, `ptrdiff_t`, `uint64_t` will usually just compile and run. Code that has abuse for `int` everywhere as loop variables, does `char` arithmetic forgetting that this might be signed or unsigned, and stuff like that is seeking for trouble. Run your code through different compilers with all warnings on, `clang` is a good complement to `gcc`

Comment: @Jens: thanks for the additional comments - the point about building and testing with multiple compilers is a very good one.

Answer (score 1):

Simply don't rely on assumption of the machine word size? always use sizeof, stdint.h, etc. Unless you rely on different library calls for different architectures, there should be no need for #ifdefs.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest strategy is to build what you have with 64-bit settings and test the heck out of it. Some code doesn't need to change at all. Other code, usually with wrong assumptions about the size of ints/pointers will be much more brittle and will need to be modified to be non-dependant on the architecture.

Very often binary files containing binary records cause the most problems. This is especially true in environments where ints grow from 32-bit to 64-bit in the transition to a 64-bit build. Primarily this is due to the fact that integers get written natively to files in their current (32-bit) length and read in using an incorrect length in a 64-bit build where ints are 64-bit.

Comment: It depends on the compiler of course, but all the 64 bit C compilers I have used (gcc, clang), leave `int` at 32 bits and make `long` 64 bits.

Comment: @JeremyP: It depends on the platform data model (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit#Specific_C-language_data_models) rather than the compiler.  For example on Win64 both `int` and `long` remain 32bit, while `long long` is 64 bit, so the model is identical to Win32 for integers, but pointers become 64 bit, so code that attempts to use an `int` or `long` to hold a pointer value will fail - change to `intptr_t` where required.